# Removing duplicate entries of cell array MATLAB

Tags: arrays, file, matlab, text-files, cell

I am facing a problem. i have a huge data file in text format and the entries are in this format:

**18 1 1471-213X-6-54-12 503 5.333333e-001 xyz**

the First column range from 1-22 and first column and third column must not be duplicated. If duplicated values exists i want to remove them. I am working in Matlab. 
I could not find any suitable stuff to solve this problem. 
Anybody hint/help will highly be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Mehdi

Comment: Is this a 2-dimensional cell array, a cell array of strings, or what?

Comment: What exactly should be done to duplicate values? Should all duplicates be removed or should only topmost be saved, or only should only the bottommost be saved or how? Or should entire row be deleted in the case field 1 or field 3 is a duplicate with any other field 1 or field 3, and again should all such duplicate rows be deleted, or should only topmost or bottommost be saved? Please provide example input and the desired example output (a short example text file something like 3-10 rows, before and after the removal of duplicates, to understand what you are attempting to do).

Comment: Until additional information is added to the post, I vote to close.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint, suppose your first column is called `f`, and your third colum is called `t`.
you may be interested in the following commands:

```
[xxx,IA_f] = unique(f) 
[xxx,IA_t] = unique(t) 
[xxx,IA_tf] = unique([f t], 'rows')
```

Assuming that your data is in matrix'M' and you have selected `IA` as the proper index, you can do:

```
M_unique = M(IA,:)
```